# SSRS report ERROR "Could not load folder contents Something went wrong. Please try again later. "

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs, ssrs-2016

One of our report servers is raising errors when trying to reach it from clients computers and works just fine from the actual server.
the error is:
[image: error]

I found that it was a bug in sql 2016 using this article by Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3172981

I upgraded to SP2 and then upgraded to the last CU update as Microsoft suggested but it still didn't work.

1. Other things i tried that did not work:
2. adding permission from SSRS
3. changing ssrs service user and giving it local admin as well
4. giving permissions from ssms to the service user.
5. looking at event viewer and error log for an error which i didn't see.
6. opening IE as admin
7. compering IE security configuration
8. changing the service from automatic to automtic with delay
9. changing UTC
10. reinstalling the instance installing CU1 for RTM, SP1,
    SP2..
11. comparing config file to an sql ssrs 2016 that works
12. comparing IE version with ssrs server that works..

errorlog:

appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!414!08/16/2018-12:22:19:: i INFO: Registering AppDomain: type='ReportServer'; id='3'; Name='ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-1-131788849389917877'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!414!08/16/2018-12:22:19:: i INFO: Creating a new AppDomainLifeCycleManagementEntry for AppDomain id '3'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!414!08/16/2018-12:22:19:: i INFO: Appdomain STARTED: id='3'; name='ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-1-131788849389917877'
appdomainmanager!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:23:: i INFO: RS authentication mode is 4; effective ASP.NET authentication mode is Windows. vdir=/ReportServer.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!414!08/16/2018-12:22:23:: i INFO: Appdomain:3 ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-1-131788849389917877 initialized (#1).
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!414!08/16/2018-12:22:23:: i INFO: SetInitialized AppDomain id '3': initialized = 1
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Reporting Web Server started
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: SQLDump flags: ReferencedMemory, AllThreads, SendToWatson
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: MiniDump flags: DataSegs, UnloadedModules, ProcessThreadData
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Dump on: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogExceptionMicrosoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingExceptionMicrosoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Do not dump on: System.Threading.ThreadAbortExceptionSystem.Web.UI.ViewStateExceptionSystem.OutOfMemoryExceptionSystem.Web.HttpExceptionSystem.IO.IOExceptionSystem.IO.FileLoadExceptionMicrosoft.SharePoint.SPExceptionMicrosoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderExceptionSystem.AppDomainUnloadedException
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Minidump location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\Logfiles
runningjobs!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Running Requests Scavenger timer enabled: Next Event: 60 seconds.  Cycle: 60 seconds
runningjobs!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Running Requests DB timer enabled: Next Event: 60 seconds.  Cycle: 60 seconds
resourceutilities!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Enterprise
ui!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Installed SKU: Enterprise edition
ui!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:50:: i INFO: Software Usage Metrics not enabled for Enterprise edition
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:51:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:51:: i INFO: Catalog SQL Server Edition = Enterprise
crypto!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:51:: i INFO: Initializing crypto as user: BRIUTNT\vmbi
crypto!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:51:: i INFO: Exporting public key
crypto!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:52:: i INFO: Importing existing encryption key
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:52:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:52:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:52:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:52:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-1!414!08/16/2018-12:22:52:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b1c!08/16/2018-12:27:18:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b1c!08/16/2018-12:27:18:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b1c!08/16/2018-12:27:18:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b1c!08/16/2018-12:27:18:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!1b1c!08/16/2018-12:27:18:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b1c!08/16/2018-12:27:18:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
library!WindowsService_0!58!08/16/2018-12:28:52:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
library!WindowsService_0!58!08/16/2018-12:28:52:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 0 sessions, 0 cache entries, 0 snapshots, 0 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 0 segments, 0 segment mappings, 0 edit sessions.
library!WindowsService_0!58!08/16/2018-12:28:52:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
library!ReportServer_0-1!1838!08/16/2018-12:32:18:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1838!08/16/2018-12:32:18:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-1!1838!08/16/2018-12:32:18:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1838!08/16/2018-12:32:18:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!1838!08/16/2018-12:32:18:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-1!1838!08/16/2018-12:32:18:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
library!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:37:18:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:37:18:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:37:18:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:37:18:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:37:18:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:37:18:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
library!WindowsService_0!2244!08/16/2018-12:38:52:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
library!WindowsService_0!2244!08/16/2018-12:38:52:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 0 sessions, 0 cache entries, 0 snapshots, 0 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 0 segments, 0 segment mappings, 0 edit sessions.
library!WindowsService_0!2244!08/16/2018-12:38:52:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b0!08/16/2018-12:42:18:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b0!08/16/2018-12:42:18:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b0!08/16/2018-12:42:18:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b0!08/16/2018-12:42:18:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!1b0!08/16/2018-12:42:18:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-1!1b0!08/16/2018-12:42:18:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
library!ReportServer_0-1!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:18:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:18:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-1!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:18:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-1!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:18:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:18:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-1!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:18:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1848!08/16/2018-12:47:59:: i INFO: SetUnloadStarted AppDomain id '3': unloadStarted = 1
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1848!08/16/2018-12:48:29:: i INFO: SetUnloadStarted AppDomain id '3': unloadStarted = 2
webserver!ReportServer_0-1!4a4!08/16/2018-12:48:29:: i INFO: Reporting Web Server stopped
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1844!08/16/2018-12:48:34:: i INFO: Unregistering AppDomain id='3'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1844!08/16/2018-12:48:34:: i INFO: Unregistering AppDomain: searching for AppDomain id '3'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1844!08/16/2018-12:48:34:: i INFO: Appdomain:3 ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-1-131788849389917877 unregistered.
rshost!rshost!1844!08/16/2018-12:48:34:: i INFO: Application domain type ReportServer statistics: created: 1, unloaded: 1, failed: 0, timed out: 0.
library!WindowsService_0!2244!08/16/2018-12:48:52:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
library!WindowsService_0!2244!08/16/2018-12:48:52:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 0 sessions, 0 cache entries, 0 snapshots, 0 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 0 segments, 0 segment mappings, 0 edit sessions.
library!WindowsService_0!2244!08/16/2018-12:48:52:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:18:: i INFO: Registering AppDomain: type='ReportServer'; id='4'; Name='ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-131788867384302225'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:18:: i INFO: Creating a new AppDomainLifeCycleManagementEntry for AppDomain id '4'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:18:: i INFO: Appdomain STARTED: id='4'; name='ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-131788867384302225'
appdomainmanager!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:20:: i INFO: RS authentication mode is 4; effective ASP.NET authentication mode is Windows. vdir=/ReportServer.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:20:: i INFO: Appdomain:4 ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-2-131788867384302225 initialized (#2).
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:20:: i INFO: SetInitialized AppDomain id '4': initialized = 1
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:26:: i INFO: Reporting Web Server started
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: SQLDump flags: ReferencedMemory, AllThreads, SendToWatson
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: MiniDump flags: DataSegs, UnloadedModules, ProcessThreadData
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Dump on: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogExceptionMicrosoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingExceptionMicrosoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Do not dump on: System.Threading.ThreadAbortExceptionSystem.Web.UI.ViewStateExceptionSystem.OutOfMemoryExceptionSystem.Web.HttpExceptionSystem.IO.IOExceptionSystem.IO.FileLoadExceptionMicrosoft.SharePoint.SPExceptionMicrosoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderExceptionSystem.AppDomainUnloadedException
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Minidump location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\Logfiles
runningjobs!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Running Requests Scavenger timer enabled: Next Event: 60 seconds.  Cycle: 60 seconds
runningjobs!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Running Requests DB timer enabled: Next Event: 60 seconds.  Cycle: 60 seconds
resourceutilities!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Enterprise
ui!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Installed SKU: Enterprise edition
ui!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Software Usage Metrics not enabled for Enterprise edition
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Catalog SQL Server Edition = Enterprise
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Initializing crypto as user: BRIUTNT\vmbi
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Exporting public key
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Importing existing encryption key
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-2!2010!08/16/2018-12:52:27:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)
library!ReportServer_0-2!2290!08/16/2018-12:57:18:: i INFO: Call to GetItemTypeAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-2!2290!08/16/2018-12:57:18:: i INFO: Entering StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command = 
library!ReportServer_0-2!2290!08/16/2018-12:57:18:: i INFO: Call to ListParentsAction(/). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
library!ReportServer_0-2!2290!08/16/2018-12:57:18:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!2290!08/16/2018-12:57:18:: i INFO: Processed folder '/'
library!ReportServer_0-2!2290!08/16/2018-12:57:18:: i INFO: Exiting StreamRequestHandler.ExecuteCommand - Command =  (success)

Any advice?

Comment: Enable remote errors on the reporting services instance. Does this give you any more information?

Comment: This will probably fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891363/could-not-load-folder-contents-ssrs-report-manager

Comment: @sting theres full permission on ssrs on the folder

Comment: dimuser i'll check how to do that and reply. thanks

Comment: You missed the additional info: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles\ contains detailed error info. And from experience you may want to reassign the SSRS user with SQL Configuration Manager because does things underneath the hood besides just assigning the user to the service--like permissions.

Comment: ok maybe because i assigned the user from services.msc and not configuration manager I'll also look into that.

Comment: what is startup type of Reporting Services? If it is Automatic change to Automatic (Delayed start)

Comment: @cr241 yes its automatic.ill try that thank you.

Comment: @CR241 service automatic delay didn't work

Comment: Please post the content of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`somewhere as @Sting already asked.

Comment: i did not realize he asked me for it..editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question finally.
the problem was and i quote from Microsoft article:

> If you are deploying Reporting Services in a network that uses the Kerberos protocol for mutual authentication, you must create a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the Report Server service if you configure it to run as a domain user account.

the article:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/register-a-service-principal-name-spn-for-a-report-server?view=sql-server-2017

and we were using kerberos protocol (which we didn't know) so by creating an spn we solved the issue.
thanks for everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what I did that made it work but let me tell you the steps I took.

Firstly, I was getting an error pop message saying: **You are not allowed to view this folder**

At this point, this is how my home page looked like. Notice that there was no action called: **Manage Folder**

[image: SSRS before]

So after an hour of googling and frustration, I found out that:

- SSRS *wants* you to use Internet Explorer. Edge can be configured to run in IE mode. They seem to want you to open IE as admin as well

Anyway, since I am running on Windows 11 I decided to connect to my company's network then RDP into a server there that has IE and try to connect to my SSRS from its browser.

I didn't have to get that far.

Once I connected to the company network, my PC was assigned a private IP of 10.10.0.54, I decided to first try connecting to SSRS using the private IP and voila, it worked. The browser asked me for my login and I got the permissions I wanted.

[image: SSRS after connecting to company network]

So thats it guys, you must have a network connection to your company network. Probably because SSRS wants to authenticate you using the domain controller.

You'll know you're on the right track when the browser asks for your login details.

Also you should be able to login from any browser, not just IE. The moment the

[image: MOZILLA SRSS]

That Manage Folder action button on the SSRS web page is what you're looking for.